# CMakeLists unable to find newly installed HDF5?

Tags: linux, boost, makefile, cmake

I'm working on a program that worked on another computer (1st one) and trying to get it to work on my new computer (3rd one). When I go to `build` and type `ccmake ..`, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at build/share/cmake/hdf5/hdf5-targets.cmake:67 (message):
   The imported target "hdf5" references the file


 "/home/myname/Desktop/MyProject/build/lib/libhdf5.a"

   but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

   * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

   * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

   * The installation package was faulty and contained


 "/home/myname/Desktop/MyProject/build/share/cmake/hdf5/h
df5-targets.cmake"

   but not all the files it references.

 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   build/share/cmake/hdf5/hdf5-config.cmake:70 (INCLUDE)
   build/share/cmake/hdf5/FindHDF5.cmake:85 (INCLUDE)
   src/Thing/CMakeLists.txt:66 (find_package)
```

Even when I then installed hdf5 using sudo apt-get, I got the same error

I had to delete that `lib` directory because it contained boost files that are outdated and caused a huge list of errors, possibly because of a conflict since I newly installed boost files in `usr/lib` and `usr/include` on this new computer. I got this program to work on a 2nd computer by simply deleting that `lib` directory

Is the way to resolve this to change the `CMakeLists.txt` so that it refers to the directory of the newly installed hdf5? The `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT (Projectname)


# CMake Modules
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/share/cmake/hdf5
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake
  ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

SET(ENV{HDF5_ROOT_DIR_HINT} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

# Build output 
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
mark_as_advanced(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH)


#other stuff I excluded to keep this brief
```

Also, even if I delete all the files in the `lib` directory at `home/myname/Desktop/MyProject/build/lib` except for `libhdf5.a`, I get a bunch of boost errors. Its a very long output and I think its because `make` creates new boost files in `lib` that were originally from `home/myname/Desktop/MyProject/build/lib`, instead of referring to the newly installed boost files in `usr/lib` and `usr/include`

In case it helps, line 66 of `src/Thing/CMakeLists.txt` looks like`find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS C CXX)`

I could also post the contents of `hdf5-config.cmake` and `FindHDF5.cmake`, if necessary

EDIT: `dpkg -l | greap hdf5` gives

```
ii  hdf5-helpers                                  1.8.15-patch1+docs-4                       amd64        Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - Helper tools
ii  hdf5-tools                                    1.8.15-patch1+docs-4                       amd64        Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - Runtime tools
ii  libhdf5-10:amd64                              1.8.15-patch1+docs-4                       amd64        Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - runtime files - serial version
ii  libhdf5-cpp-10:amd64                          1.8.15-patch1+docs-4                       amd64        Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - C++ libraries
ii  libhdf5-dev                                   1.8.15-patch1+docs-4                       amd64        Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - development files - serial version
ii  libhdf5-openmpi-10:amd64                      1.8.15-patch1+docs-4                       amd64        Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - runtime files - OpenMPI version
ii  libhdf5-openmpi-dev                           1.8.15-patch1+docs-4                       amd64        Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - development files - OpenMPI version
ii  libhdf5-serial-dev                            1.8.15-patch1+docs-4                       all          transitional dummy package
```

Comment: Do you have `libhdf5-dev` installed? `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`

Comment: I installed it with `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev`. When I try `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`, it says it `libhdf5-dev is already the newest version.`

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/hdf5 says that it's a transitional package. I would make sure that all necessary development files are actually in the FS. `dpkg -l | grep hdf5` and then inspect content of each `-dev` package listed with `dpkg -L`.

Comment: BTW, what is your _final_ goal? Do you plan to link against a static library to avoid need to bother if libhdf5 is installed on a target computer? And yes if you use a custom libhdf5 somewhere in your tree, then you shouldn't mix it with header files installed system-wide. So in this case for the sake of simplicity you should remove all libhdf5*-dev packages at least for a while and then build the program against headers of the library in your build tree.

Comment: sorry, I'm rather new to linux so I don't follow alot of what you're saying. I posted the contents of `dpkg -l | grep hdf5` in the OP. I'm not sure how I can find the necessary missing files by using `dpkg -L` for each `-dev` package?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to link the static libraries. As for libhdf5, the program I'm using is rather large and I don't think I've used hdf before, so I'm not sure why my program requires it. I remember on the 2nd computer I worked with, I didn't get this hdf5 error, but maybe it was already installed. How do I remove the libhdf5-dev packages?

Comment: According to error log, `hdf5` package is expected in the *build directory* (under `/home/myname/Desktop/MyProject/build`), so `dpkg` has nothing common with this problem, as it installs packages into *system-wide* directories. If you want CMake to search your package in system-wide directories, you needn't to pass hints about your build directory, like you do with setting `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` and `HDF5_ROOT_DIR_HINT` (which should be `HDF5_ROOT` according to source of [findHDF5.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindHDF5.cmake)).

Answer (score 7):

A not so short introduction to linking of third-party libraries on Linux:

Generally you should decide 2 aspects.

The first one is about "system vs custom library"

1. you may link your application against a library installed from a system package (in Debian using `apt-get`). This is the preferred way to compile programs on Linux unless you have some reasons against (see below). Also  usually this is the easiest way, 'cause all build tools are configured to find library components in certain "well-known" places.
2. Link against a custom build of a library. Use this method if you need some custom build options for a library, or need a specific version of library not available in repostitories and so on.

The second step is to choose between static and dynamic library.

1. Usually in Linux applications are linked against dynamically loaded libraries (`.so`). This reduces applications size, *may* decrease memory consumption and application loading time (because libraries for a given application are in memory already), and sometimes simplifies small updates like security fixes - one needs to update just a single library instead of all applications that use this vulnerable library
2. But there're drawbacks as well :) If you plan to distribute your application linked with dynamic libraries to other computers you need to make sure that the libraries of *required versions* are on a given target computer. Each library may in turn be linked with other libraries and so on. In the end you have to distribute a whole copy of an operating system, like e.g. Steam for Linux does: internally it carries a large part of Ubuntu. So sometimes it may be wiser to link against a *static library* and include everything needed rignt into your app.

Back to the practical questions. Since you've already installed system packages with libhdf5 development files (`libhdf5-dev`) I suggest you to go with the "system library" (p1.1).

In this case you should remove all other copies of the library from your build tree completely and use the following code chunk in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)
...
include_directories(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
target_link_libraries(yourapp ${HDF5_LIBRARIES} <other required libs>)
```

if your application is a C++ app you may use `${HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES}` instead of `${HDF5_LIBRARIES}`.

**If you decided to link against a static library**, then you need to define a special variable `HDF5_USE_STATIC_LIBRARIES` *before* calling `find_package(HDF5...)`:

```
 set(HDF5_USE_STATIC_LIBRARIES ON)
 find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)
 ...
```

If you still wish to use a custom build of the library then you should 
"explain" to `find_package` where to look for library components. You may run `make DESTDIR=/some/path install` in the *HDF5 build tree* and then use that `/some/path` as the value of `HDF5_ROOT` environmental variable when running cmake in your application build tree:

```
  HDF5_ROOT=/some/path cmake .
```

In this case CMake will try to locate HDF5 components in that directory. I would remove sytem package `libhdf5-dev` before this operation (just in case) using `apt-get remove libhdf5-dev`.

But again I believe that you should have good reasons not to use the system libhdf5 package.